# Is there a replacement for Fences?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a replacement for the [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) application for Ubuntu 11.10?

Fences lets you organize the icons and application shortcuts on the desktop by creating containers for the desktop icons. It is different from Folderview. Folderview shows the contents of the folder in a container but Fences lets you organize the desktop icons into a container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sreenlets has a similar widget for Ubuntu desktop. You can install Screenlets from the "Ubuntu software centre". [Here is the Widget](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=102890)

Answer (score 2):

KDE has a similar way of displaying icons by default.